# Namedpipe to list while being able to read or use that list?

Tags: c#, list, .net-3.5, named-pipes

Let's say I have a list and am streaming data from a namedpipe to that list.

hypothetical sample:

```
private void myStreamingThread()
{
    while(mypipe.isconnected)
    {
       if (mypipe.hasdata)
           myList.add(mypipe.data);
    }
}
```

Then on another thread I need to read that list every 1000ms for example:

```
private void myListReadingThread()
{
    while(isStarted)
    {
       if (myList.count > 0)
       {
           //do whatever I need to.
       }
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

My priority here is to be able to read the list every 1000 ms and do whatever I need with the list but at the same time it is very important to be able to get the new data from it that comes from the pipe.

**What is a good method to come with this ?**

Forgot to mention I am tied to .NET 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a ConcurrentQueue (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx).  If you use a simple List<> then you will encourter a lot threading issues.

The other practice would be to use a mutex called outstandingWork and wait on it instead of Thread.Sleep().  Then when you enqueue some work you pulse outstandingWork.  This means that you sleep when no work is available but start processing work immediately instead of sleep the entire 1 second.

**Edit**

As @Prix pointed out, you are using .Net 3.5.  So you cannot use ConcurrentQueue.  Use the Queue class with the following

```
Queue<Work> queue;
AutoResetEvent outstandingWork = new AutoResetEvent(false);

void Enqueue(Work work) 
{
    lock (queue)
    { 
       queue.Enqueue(work); 
       outstandingWork.Set();
    }
}

Work DequeMaybe()
{
    lock (queue)
    {
       if (queue.Count == 0) return null;
       return queue.Dequeue();
    }
}

void DoWork()
{
   while (true)
   {
      Work work = DequeMaybe();
      if (work == null)
      {
          outstandingWork.WaitOne();
          continue;
      }
      // Do the work.
   }
}
```

Comment: @Richard that did be awesome but it says .Net 4

Comment: Using the mutex wouldnt that fail at some point since the pipe can send new data at any time, if it sends at a time I am reading the list it would fail on the pipe writting and vice-versa no ? And thanks for replying ;)

Comment: It should work, because the Wait only happens when the queue is empty.  So it will pickup the mutex being set.

Comment: @Richard thanks i will go thru it and see how it works out for me.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx) with a lock.

```
Queue<string> myQueue = new Queue<string>();

private void myStreamingThread()
{
    while(mypipe.isconnected)
    {
       if (mypipe.hasdata)
       {
           lock (myQueue)
           {
               myQueue.add(mypipe.data);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

If you want to empty the queue every 1000 ms, do not use `Thread.Sleep`. Use a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) instead.

```
System.Threading.Timer t = new Timer(myListReadingProc, null, 1000, 1000);


private void myListReadingProc(object s)
{
   while (myQueue.Count > 0)
   {
       lock (myQueue)
       {
           string item = myQueue.Dequeue();
           // do whatever
       }
    }
}
```

Note that the above assumes that the queue is only being read by one thread. If multiple threads are reading, then there's a race condition. But the above will work with a single reader and one or more writers.

Comment: This has a race condition.  You are test the Count outside of a lock.  So count could be greater than zero, but when get the lock the queue could be empty!

Comment: @Richard: If you read the comment at the end, I mentioned that race condition and noted that it's okay for a single reader. For multiple readers, simply add another check of `Count` inside the lock.

Comment: very appreciated, it seems to works just fine since i only have a single reader.